# Google карта не реагирует на android > 5

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Использую Google карты в своем приложении и при компиляции на `android 4.4.2` работают нормально, а в `android 6` не реагирует ни на что.

Когда выводил карты из `Fragment`a android 6 запрашивает разрешение на определение местонахождения, и когда нажимаю разрешить тоже останавливаются карты. Потом решил так сделать:

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

```
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker))
            .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)
            .position(new LatLng(43, 543, 45, 652))
            .flat(true)
            .title(title));
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что в логе про инициализацию карты?

Comment: Оказывается нужно было использовать метод onRequestPermissionsResult. Все получилось. Вопрос закрыт)